# GPSD, How to get the last known location?

Tags: geolocation, gpsd

if GPS-module disconnected,
or if GPS antenna gets moved into building, I wan't to know the last available location.

I tried to log location every 10 or so seconds with systemd-timers; However, exactly when log-file is updating every 10 sec, there is an instance `cat` -ing log-file returns empty. This needs to be robust as possible, since inexperienced user will be operating the system.

Are there anything tools within GPSD tools that provide this?

Comment: Instead of just cat-ing the log file, have you tried checking if the logfile is empty and sleeping until it isn't?   e.g. something like `until [ -s "/path/to/logfile" ] ; do sleep 0.01 ; done` before the `cat` (note: the quotes around the logfile path aren't necessary unless the path contains whitespace etc, or the path is in a variable).   In bash, the `-s` test is *True if file exists and is not empty.*   See `help test`.   If that helps solve your problem, please write it up as a detailed answer, you can accept your own answer in a day or so.